# using return key to trigger a click on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have a simple form where users can enter comments then click return, which submits the form.

Problem is, this does not work on ipad and I cannot understand why?

This is the code:

```
if (event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey && this.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length > 0) 
    {
        $(".post").trigger('click');
        return false;
    }
```

Question is: how can I make this work on ipad?

Comment: is this a hybrid application?

Comment: Its a web app but resize responsive etc for different platforms

Comment: so you are just opening the page in a web view?

Comment: Yeah thats correct, its a simple web page